# Adding dependencies without rosdep

Tags: ros, rosdep, catkin, dependencies, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not have root access on a system that I am trying to install ROS on.  I've had some success so far using a python virtualenv, but that has not allowed me to run rosdep.  Currently, my catkin build stops while building roslib, saying "Project 'roslib' tried to find library 'tinyxml'".  I tried installing tinyxml on my own and manually adding it to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but that does not seem to work.  Any tips?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53619/adding-dependencies-without-rosdep/) by [BigBlueDart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3937/bigbluedart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add tinyxml to your PKG_CONFIG_PATH, because tinyxml is found using pkg-config.  You'll know that your environment is setup correctly when you can run `pkg-config --libs tinyxml` and get reasonable output.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BigBlueDart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3937/bigbluedart/) on 2013-02-06**:
I tried this, but when running the pkg-config command it tells me it can't find the library and that it is looking for a tinyxml.pc file.  When I built tinyxml it made no such file.  Any tips on that?